# How to save inherited model attributes directly from request?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a base model `BaseNote` and two inherited from it: `ReferenceNote` and `TaskNote`. `TaskNote` has an additional attribute `start_date`. `ReferenceNote` has `text` attribute.
In request I have `type` and my code of creation of new note:

```
$noteType = self::getNoteType($request->get('type'));
$note = $noteType::create($request->all());
```

This code save only `BaseNote` attributes. 
Can I make this code work without making two factory methods and manually assign attributes? Can Laravel get attributes from request and automatically assign them to model?

UPDATE:

```
 static function getNoteType($type)
    {
        switch ($type) {
            case self::REFERENCE_NOTE:
                return 'App\models\notes\ReferenceNote';
                break;
            case self::TASK_NOTE:
                return 'App\models\notes\TaskNote';
                break;
            default:
                return 'App\models\notes\ReferenceNote';
        }
    }
```

In `ReferenceNote` and `TaskNote` models I have `$guarded = []`.

I have one table `notes` which contains all columns (and `ReferenceNote` and `TaskNote`).

Comment: Does your database table correspond to your model?

Comment: Database includes all columns (and `ReferenceNote` columns and `TaskNote` columns).

Comment: Can you show the code for getNoteType? Does it save it to the BaseNote table or the child tables? Can you also show your or fillable attr from your child models?